# Where to place calls to route() within Package's Service Provider?

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5.4, package-development

I have 2 Laravel packages; one for managing an admin panel. And the second one for filling it with useful pages.

Now the first package; let's call it AdminPackage from now on. Has a built in Menu Manager which allows me to register new headers & menu links from outside of the package.

The idea is that in my second package, which adds functionality to the first, can call the `AdminPackage::menu()->addHeader()` and the `AdminPackage::menu()->addLink()` methods to add some links to the navigation of the admin panel.

But now comes the problem:

When I call the method in my 2nd package's Service Provider I get the following error:

`InvalidArgumentException
Route [route-name] not defined.`

I have also tried putting the code directly in the Service I'm binding to the IoC container within my ServiceProvider. But same problem.

I get the error using it in both the boot() and register() method. So the routes have not been fully loaded at this point in time.

How can I solve this problem? I need to wait for the routes to finish loading and call the menu manager methods before the page is rendered and the menu items are displayed.

Thanks in advance!